# Maximal acyclic edge set vs maximum acyclic edge set

Tags: graph-theory

As the title indicates, I have a hard time visualizing cases where the maximum ac. edge set has an exceeding cardinality over a maximal ac. edge set. If someone can provide me with such a case or prove the otherway correct, you will be most welcome.

EDIT: TO clarify I am asking for people to provide a visual example of a case where for graph G the cardinality of a maximum acyclic edge set exceeds that of a maximal acyclic edge set. Or is it, not the case always?

Acc to me:

1. Maximal ac. edge set - adding anymore edges from E(G) makes the set cyclic
   (i.e there exists a subset of edges that can form a cycle)
2. Maximum ac. edge set - !!!All maximal ac. edge sets are maximum ac. edge sets.!!!
   (This is where I struggle to understand, I cannot think of a case where this is wrong)

I can visualize the same for maximal/maximum matchings. If my phrasing is anywhere incorrect please correct me, I might be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maximal and maximum edge sets that are acyclic are the same. These correspond to spanning trees if the graph is connected.

Comment: @MathieuRundström Can you suggest me a proof for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that any tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges (you can prove this by induction). Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n$ vertices. $G$ has a spanning tree $T$, which has $n-1$ edges. Any additional edge added to $T$ creates a cycle, since any two vertices in $T$ are connected by a path. Thus $E(T)$ is a maximal acyclic edge set. Any set of at least $n$ edges in $G$ contains a cycle, since all trees on $n$ vertices have $n-1$ edges. Thus $T$ is maximum. Suppose now that $F$ is a maximal acyclic subset of $E(G)$. If $|F|<n-1$, then $F$ is a forest with at least two components. Since $G$ is connected, $F$ has two components $C_1$ and $C_2$ joined by an edge $e$ in $G$. Then $F+e$ is acyclic, a contradiction to maximality.

If the graph you are insterested in is not connected, apply the above argument to each component.